# Meteor 0.8.3 updated to 0.9.3 cannot start "TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined"

Tags: meteor

I did
`meteor update`

All packages are manually added via `meteor add`
Here is the log:

```
=> Started proxy.
=> Started MongoDB.
=> Starting your app...
/Users/test/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.1b5lzqo++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/fibers/future.js:173
            throw(ex);
                  ^
TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined
  at /Users/test/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.1b5lzqo++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/compiler.js:378:34
  at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/test/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.1b5lzqo++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:87:22)
  at /Users/test/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.1b5lzqo++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/compiler.js:371:7
  at Array.forEach (native)
  at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/test/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.1b5lzqo++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
  at compileUnibuild (/Users/test/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.1b5lzqo++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/compiler.js:370:5)
  at /Users/test/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.1b5lzqo++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/compiler.js:888:27
  at Array.forEach (native)
  at Function._.each._.forEach (/Users/test/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.1b5lzqo++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/dev_bundle/lib/node_modules/underscore/underscore.js:79:11)
  at Object.compiler.compile (/Users/test/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.1b5lzqo++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/compiler.js:887:5)
  at /Users/test/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.1b5lzqo++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/bundler.js:1794:26
  at /Users/test/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.1b5lzqo++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:247:13
  at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/Users/test/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.1b5lzqo++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:112:14)
  at /Users/test/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.1b5lzqo++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:240:29
  at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/Users/test/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.1b5lzqo++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:112:14)
  at /Users/test/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.1b5lzqo++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:238:18
  at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/Users/test/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.1b5lzqo++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:112:14)
  at /Users/test/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.1b5lzqo++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:229:23
  at [object Object]._.extend.withValue (/Users/test/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.1b5lzqo++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/fiber-helpers.js:112:14)
  at Object.capture (/Users/test/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.1b5lzqo++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/buildmessage.js:228:19)
  at Object.exports.bundle (/Users/test/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.1b5lzqo++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/bundler.js:1716:31)
  at bundleApp (/Users/test/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.1b5lzqo++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/run-app.js:481:28)
  at [object Object]._.extend._runOnce (/Users/test/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.1b5lzqo++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/run-app.js:499:24)
  at [object Object]._.extend._fiber (/Users/test/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.1b5lzqo++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/run-app.js:685:28)
  at /Users/test/.meteor/packages/meteor-tool/.1.0.33.1b5lzqo++os.osx.x86_64+web.browser+web.cordova/meteor-tool-os.osx.x86_64/tools/run-app.js:360:12
```

Answer (score 0):

OK the error is gone if I delete all the symlinks in `/packages/` folder.

See [discover meteor's blog post](https://www.discovermeteor.com/blog/updating-to-090/) for why you can delete that folder.